# Porque me sale este error justo cuando actualizo mi versión de android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

He actualizado mi versión de `Android Studio` y aparecen una serie de errores quisiera saber porque esto sucede y porque no puedo arrancar mi proyecto si antes de actualizar corría muy bien. 
 Al querer compilar la mayoría de mis proyectos (excepto los que he creado después de la actualización), me salen con este error:

Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

Could not find google-services.json while looking in [src/nullnull/debug, src/debug/nullnull, src/nullnull, src/debug, src/nullnullDebug]
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
:app:buildInfoDebugLoader
:app:checkDebugClasspath UP-TO-DATE
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugGoogleServices
Parsing json file: C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\la Gloria es de DIOS\CentinelaUniversal\app\google-services.json
:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
:app:buildInfoGeneratorDebug

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'. java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource
>     compilation failed   Output:  C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\la Gloria es de
>     DIOS\CentinelaUniversal\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-en\values-en.xml:31:
>     error: unescaped apostrophe in string   "Occasionally we could have
>     entered incorrect data,
>           So it's a good practice, analyze them again.".   C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\la Gloria es de
>     DIOS\CentinelaUniversal\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-en\values-en.xml:30:
>     error: not a valid string.
>      Command: C:\Users\Usuario.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows.jar\2c12985414798bfd63cd54dabe572867\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe
>     compile --legacy \
>           -o \
>           C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\la Gloria es de DIOS\CentinelaUniversal\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug \
>           C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\la Gloria es de DIOS\CentinelaUniversal\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-en\values-en.xml
>     Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows Daemon #0   Output: 
>     C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\la Gloria es de
>     DIOS\CentinelaUniversal\app\src\main\res\values-en\strings.xml:85:5-86:92:
>     AAPT: error: unescaped apostrophe in string
>          "Occasionally we could have entered incorrect data,
>           So it's a good practice, analyze them again.".   C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\la Gloria es de
>     DIOS\CentinelaUniversal\app\src\main\res\values-en\strings.xml:81:5-82:62:
>     AAPT: error: not a valid string.
>          Command: C:\Users\Usuario.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows.jar\2c12985414798bfd63cd54dabe572867\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe
>     compile --legacy \
>           -o \
>           C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\la Gloria es de DIOS\CentinelaUniversal\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug \
>           C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\la Gloria es de DIOS\CentinelaUniversal\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-en\values-en.xml
>     Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows Daemon #0
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 8s 12 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 8 up-to-date
>   Exception in thread "ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1"
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: AAPT Process manager cannot be shut
>   down while daemons are in use     at
>   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonManager.shutdown(Aapt2DaemonManager.kt:96)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.namespaced.RegisteredAaptService.shutdown(Aapt2DaemonManagerService.kt:61)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.workeractions.WorkerActionServiceRegistry$shutdownAllRegisteredServices$1$1.run(WorkerActionServiceRegistry.kt:96)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1402)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)

Me sale ese error y no se por donde empezar

Comment: y cual es el error?

Comment: Lo acabe de editar mostrando el mensaje de error que muestra.

Comment: proba con build - clean project - build rebuild project

Comment: ya hice eso muchas veces bro